# R Replace names in multiple columns with ID's from another object

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have a set of patient data `df` I am trying to de-identify in R.

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Andrew", 
                                                                      "Jim", "Kurt", "Lester", "Mickey", "Taylor"), class = "factor"), 
               heart_rate = c(78L, 82L, 67L, 105L, 85L, 94L), age = c(35L, 
                                                                      23L, 43L, 52L, 33L, 45L), partner = structure(c(5L, 2L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Andrew", "Jim ", "Kurt ", "Lester ", 
                                                                                                                                              "Mickey ", "Taylor "), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -6L))
```

I want to replace the names of both the `name` and `partner` columns based on the `id` column of this object called `key`

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Andrew", 
"Jim", "Kurt", "Lester", "Mickey", "Taylor"), class = "factor"), 
    id = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A3", 
    "J9", "K5", "L4", "M4", "T7"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I can de-identify the `name` column with this code

```
df[["name"]] <- key[ match(df[['name']], key[['name']] ) , 'id']
```

but, when I try to de-identify the `partner` column with this code

```
df[["partner"]] <- key[ match(df[['partner']], key[['name']] ) , 'id']
```

My dataframe looks like this

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A3", 
"J9", "K5", "L4", "M4", "T7"), class = "factor"), heart_rate = c(78L, 
82L, 67L, 105L, 85L, 94L), age = c(35L, 23L, 43L, 52L, 33L, 45L
), partner = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("A3", 
"J9", "K5", "L4", "M4", "T7"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Bonus points for methods that could just apply over all columns in a dataset in one line and explanations of code are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your `partner` column in `df` there is a space after most of the words:

```
.Label = c("Andrew", "Jim ", "Kurt ", "Lester ", "Mickey ", "Taylor ")
```

This means that `match()` won't find an exact match except for the name "Andrew", for which it correctly returns that index.

The way to fix this is to remove whitespace from your `partner` column with

```
df$partner = trimws(df$partner)
```

then your code works fine:

```
> df[["partner"]] <- key[ match(df[['partner']], key[['name']] ) , 'id']
> df
  name heart_rate age partner
1   J9         78  35      M4
2   M4         82  23      J9
3   A3         67  43      T7
4   T7        105  52      A3
5   L4         85  33      K5
6   K5         94  45      L4
```